# Query to filter array value property

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have the following data in Mongo:

```
{
    "id": "foo1",
    "description": "myFoo1",
    "bars": [
        {
            "id": "foo1bar1",
            "description": "myFoo1Bar1",
            "builton": "2010-03-01T05:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "foo1bar2",
            "description": "myFoo1Bar2",
            "builton": "2011-03-01T05:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "id": "foo2",
    "description": "myFoo2",
    "bars": [
        {
            "id": "foo2bar1",
            "description": "myFoo2Bar1",
            "builton": "2012-03-01T05:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "foo2bar2",
            "description": "myFoo2Bar2",
            "builton": "2013-03-01T05:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is two-fold, I suppose:

Is it possible to execute a query that will only return documents that have a `bar` with a date between a specified range and only return the `bars` that fall in that date range? So for example, if my date range was 2010-02-01 through 2010-04-01 this is what I'd want to get back:

```
{
    "id": "foo1",
    "description": "myFoo1",
    "bars": [
        {
            "id": "foo1bar1",
            "description": "myFoo1Bar1",
            "builton": "2010-03-01T05:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this the best way to structure the data or should I do it more relationally (i.e. have two separate documents (`foos` and `bars`) and then just have a `fooId` field on `bar`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you will always get a full document back. If you really want only one element of a sub array, then your best bet would be to split each "bar" into it's own document. In this case, it would probably be better to use two collections like you'd do in an RDBMs but it is *also* possible to just store things like this:

```
{
    "foo" : {
        "id": "foo1",
        "description": "myFoo1",
    }
    "id": "foo1bar1",
    "description": "myFoo1Bar1",
    "builton": "2010-03-01T05:00:00.000Z"
},
{
    "foo" : {
        "id": "foo1",
        "description": "myFoo1",
    }
    "id": "foo1bar2",
    "description": "myFoo1Bar2",
    "builton": "2011-03-01T05:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Ie, store the "foo" information with each bar.